# How to unravel wrapped text

Tags: folding

One of the files I have has "wrapped" text :
[image]
Any idea how to unravel it?
I am not sure if this is feature of any of my plugins.
List of my plugins:

```
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup'
Plug 'pandoc-preview.vim'
Plug 'vimtex'
Plug 'vim-auto-save'
```

My vim version : `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Feb 22 2019 18:22:38)`

Comment: Not related to your question, which I've answered in the answers section. What is that list of plugins? Is it directly copied from vimrc? If yes, then why are there some lines containing `Plugin 'name'` and some just `name`? It's confusing.

Comment: I am using both Vundle and vim-plug. and I didn't copy them from `.vimrc` instead I copied output  of commands `:PlugStatus` and `:PluginList`, however now that I think about it I should've just copied them from `.vimrc`, sorry for the confusion. I have now edited them as they are in my `.vimrc`.

Comment: Off the top of my head, it's probably `vimtex` that is setting up folds for you. You might want to take a gander at `:help vimtex-folding`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all the "wrapped" text is actually a folded text (see `:h folds`)

To open the closed folds, you can

- Place your cursor on the folded texts and do `zo` to open it (see `:h zo`)
- Place your cursor on the folded text and do `za` to toggle fold under cursor, i.e. open the fold if the fold is closed and vice versa (see `:h za`)
- Do `zR` to open all the folds (see `:h zR`)
- Do `zi` to toggle the the display of folds, i.e. toggle 'foldenable' (see `:h zi` and `:h foldenable`)

For more info and keybinding to create/delete/open/close/interact with folds, see `:h folds`

Comment: Glad it worked. On an unrelated note, you should read `:h intro` to make sure you know what features are there in vim, so that you can identify whether what you are encountering is a bug/problem or a feature, even if you don't actually need or have any interest in that feature. It'll be useful. Cheers!

Comment: Or `zi` to toggle whether folds are displayed at all.

Comment: My favorite is `za`—I dont have to think about open or close.

Comment: Added `zi` and `za` to the answer.